# How to open a pdf on the iPad from an AIR for iOS app

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

I am making an AIR for iOS app that can download pdfs. I do not want to display the pdf in the app itself but want the default pdf-viewer (iBooks) to launch and show the pdf. How can this be done.

I am aware that navigateToURL can be used to open a file with the uri scheme of iBooks. But i dont know how to tell iBooks to look in the app-directory of my app. (Or is there some secret directory to place the file in from within the app - where iBooks can find it)

I have a hard time figuring out what the expected behavior should be. I can open iBooks from the app, but where should i place the file so that iBooks can get to it?

Any pointers or help would be greatly appreciated as this is somewhat of a show stopper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If simple navigateToURL won't work as expected, I'd suggest you to look at [AIR Native Extensions (ANE)](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html) and [UIDocumentInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html) (+ [blog post](http://andycodes.tumblr.com/tagged/uidocumentinteractioncontroller)).

Comment: The problem is i have a hard time figuring out what the expected behaviour should be.

Comment: Ehmmm what's the problem again? What app to use to open PDF? or how to pass PDF path to iBooks? or what?

Comment: How to pass the PDF path to iBooks?

Comment: It is described in the blog article I posted above. And ANE is here to help you to run iOS native code.

Comment: I see what you mean. I have worked with several ANEs but i have never made my own, so i guess this will be my first. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Try this library

http://code.google.com/p/pavo/

I haven't used it personally. It this works you will be able to extract text / content and render back in flash / flex application.

Comment: Hi Gaurav - Thx. I am not looking to display the pdf inside the app i am making - i want the pdf to open in the default pdf-viewer app (iBooks). If i wanted to display the pdf inside the app i think the webview class would do what i want.